# I need to hide/remove path from the url

Tags: javascript, html

I'm opening an html file from javascript which is `index.html`.The `index.html` is in another folder (index) under root folder. When `index.html` opens, the url becomes `www.abc.com/index/`

I want to remove or hide folder name index from the url. The url should display only 
`www.abc.com` wherever I redirect page. I'm opening the `index.html` using `window.open`

```
window.open("/index/","_self");
```

Comment: The location bar will always display the actual url, no way to change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For achieving that you can use an `.htaccess` file which uses the `index` directory as your root directory.

In your root directory on *www.abc.com* just create a file named `.htaccess` and paste the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now if everything is correctly set up, the url you should open in the popup should be `www.abc.com` or `/`

Comment: The answer postulates, without saying it, that `.htaccess` techniques can be used. They are not available in all HTTP servers, and they (either `.htaccess` in general or URL rewriting in particular) might be disabled by server settings. It’s unclear how this is supposed to work, as this seems to result in a URL that contains a part that should be omitted from it, according to the question.

Comment: I need to do it in lighttpd server.I have tried with url.rewrite but browser url is not changing.